# how do I exclude table field MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, field

Sorry about the strange title, but I am having a small issue if the user type is 2 or 3 then I need the user not to be able to insert or update a few fields, but instead of creating a number of insert queries listed below are a few fields I need not updated.

> AMStatus,HQStatus,approvedforsite

```
public function databaseinsert($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        switch($this->data['action']){
            case "newlead":
                $this->insert("customer_detail",
                              "TradingName,Street,City,State,PostCode,Industry,SubCategories,Membership,LeadStatus,AMStatus,HQStatus,approvedforsite,Salutation,FirstName,LastName,Website,Company,ABN_ACNNumber,Phone,Mobile,Notes,Description",
                              "'{$this->data['tradingname']}',
                              '{$this->data['street']}',
                              '{$this->data['suburb']}',
                              '{$this->data['state']}',
                              '{$this->data['postcode']}',
                              '{$this->data['category']}',
                              '{$this->data['subcategory']}',
                              '{$this->data['membership']}',
                              '{$this->data['salestatus']}',
                              '{$this->data['managerstatus']}',
                              '{$this->data['hqstatus']}',
                              '{$this->data['publishtoweb']}',
                              '{$this->data['title']}',
                              '{$this->data['firstname']}',
                              '{$this->data['lastname']}',
                              '{$this->data['webaddress']}',
                              '{$this->data['companyname']}',
                              '{$this->data['abnacn']}',
                              '{$this->data['phonenumber']}',
                              '{$this->data['mobile']}',
                              '{$this->data['notes']}',
                              '{$this->data['businessdescription']}'                              
                              ");
            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: @MichaelTodd how do I hide AMStatus,HQStatus,approvedforsite from being inserted if they dont have the correct account type (2,3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it in your script handle database fields and values by applying conditions. and make strings of both according to different user types before applying them in `$this->insert` function.

Something like below:

```
if($usertype=='yourtype')
{
$fieldsstr="TradingName,Street,City.................";
$valuestr=$this->data['tradingname'].",".$this->data['field2'].",".......

}
else
$fieldsstr="TradingName,Street.................";
$valuestr=$this->data['tradingname'].",".$this->data['field2'].",".......

}

 $this->insert("customer_detail",$fieldsstr,$valuestr);
```

Comment: could you please give an example @Teez